How to force TS to fully resolve a type alias at some point
I think the following example says it all.
/**
 * @param {ReturnType<typeof n2>} a 
 * @param {string} b
 */
function n1(a, b) { // Error: 'a' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
  return [a, b]
}

function n2() {
  /** @typedef {Parameters<typeof n1>[1]} T */ // type T = any -- Error: Type alias 'T' circularly references itself.
  return /** @param {T} ol */ (ol) => n1
}

The second parameter at index 1 is string, so I would like T to be of type string instead (which is the case if I don't bind it as the parameter type of ol.
I guess the issue lies in how TS treats type aliases. As the documentation states, "When you use the alias, it’s exactly as if you had written the aliased type." However, I need T to be evaluated outside the context of n2 or its return value. The example above is a minimal reproduction of the issue. While defining ol as string directly might work here, my actual use case is more complex.

This doesn't seem to relate to "inlining" per se, maybe we understand the term differently? I see that TS is trying to evaluate your circularly-defined types, and can't do it. And if you're expecting T to be of type string then you do want the types to be fully evaluated, not deferred. Please [edit] to remove references to "inlining" and instead talk directly about the problem you're having (not what you imagine the underlying problem is). I think this is a design limitation as per ms/TS#45213, but is unrelated to "inlining".

@jcalz Thanks for the response. As for inlining, maybe. I decided to use the term after reading this comment as I thought it would be more familiar. My understanding is that inlining is the same as what you mean by 'deferring' since it's just like doing and find-replace on every use of the name of the alias, and not directly evaluating the type the instant it is defined. I've edited the post as you suggested.

But you can write type X = {x: X} just fine. That's not "inlined" or else presumably it would be prohibited. And deferring would be the opposite of evaluating/resolving. It sounds like you expect TS to partially evaluate things, or evaluate them in a particular order, but see ms/TS#45213. Your types are truly circular (T depends on Parameters<typeof n1> depends on ReturnType<typeof n2> depends on T). See that issue and let me know if it fully addresses your question. If so I'll answer; if not, what's missing?

Thanks. I do know that the types are circular, but I believe it is not an invalid use case. What I'm looking for is a way to get around it. Also, I don't expect TS to partially evaluate the type, since it's 'just an alias'. I just want to see if there's a way to make it evaluate the type alias T so that T is string and when I write T in the parameter type of ol, it's just string, and not evaluated as Parameters<typeof n1>[1].
I'll look through the issue you linked now

Yes, please look through ms/TS#45213, since I don't have anything more intelligent to say about it than Ryan Cavanaugh, the TS team dev lead, who comments in there. Let me know if I'm missing anything and if not I'll write an answer.

So @jcalz I've just looked through the issue, and it doesn't address my concern per se. As I've mentioned earlier, I know the types are circular, by the way aliases work, and the error is expected. But is there a workaround, to make TS resolve T completely as string solely based on the type of n1 and not n2?

The only workarounds are to annotate things explicitly and not using circular references. So annotate a as string, for example. The GitHub issue and the ones linked to it all basically say the same thing: if TS gets tripped up in a circular definition, you need to help it by breaking the circularity. In essence, you know the workaround: just define your types directly, even in the "more complex" case you allude to. I know this isn't what you want to hear, but it is covered as well as can be expected in GitHub. Is something else missing or should we proceed?

Well, I don't want to type things explicitly. One interesting thing I figured though is that this works /** @typedef {{a: Parameters<typeof n1>[1]}} T */ (wrap the type in an object type), and It probably works for the same reason that type X = {x: X} works. The reason though, I'm not sure of.
